# Rudin functional analysis, theorem 3.27

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces

Few bits a bit unclear of

> a) $X$ is a topological vector space on which $X^*$ separates points, and
>
> b) $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on a compact Hausdorff space $Q$.
> If $f : Q \to X$ is continuous and if $\overline{co}(f(Q))$ is compact in $X$, then the integral
> $$
> y = \int_Q f d \mu
> $$
> exists, moreover $y \in \overline{co}(f(Q))$

Proof below:

> Regard $X$ as a real vector space. Put $H = co(f(Q))$. We have to prove that there exists $y \in H$ such that
> $$
> \Lambda y = \int_Q (\Lambda f) d \mu \;\; (2)
> $$
> for every $\Lambda \in X^*$
> Let $L = \left\{ \Lambda_1, ..., \Lambda_n \right\}$ be a finite subset of $X^*$. Let $E_L$ be the set of all $y \in \overline H$ that satisfies (2) for every $\Lambda \in L$. Each $E_L$ is closed (by continuity of $\Lambda$ and therefore compact, since $\overline{H}$ is compact.

Now there's the first bit I don't get it, despite I've tried to use the relevant theorem I can't manage anyway.

> If no $E_L$ is empty, the collection of all $E_L$ has the finite intersection property. The intersection of all $E_L$ is therefore not empty, and any $y$ in it satisfies (2) for every $\Lambda \in X^*$.

Can you please clarify those lines (like expound the details)?

The other bit I don't get is how theorem 3.20 and theorem 3.4 are used to prove the following

> Regard $L = (\Lambda_1,\ldots,\Lambda_n)$ as a mapping from $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$, and put $K = L(f(Q))$. Define
> $$
> m_i = \int_Q (\Lambda_i f) d\mu \;\; (1 \leq i \leq n)
> $$
> We claim that the point $m = (m_1,\ldots, m_n)$ lies in the convex hull of $K$. If $t = (t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ is not in this hull, then [by theorem 3.20 and (b) of theorem 3.4 and the known form of the linear functionals on $\mathbb{R}^n$] there are numbers $c_1,\ldots c_n$ such that
> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^n c_i u_i < \sum_{i=1}^n c_i t_i
> $$
> if $u = (u_1,\ldots,u_n) \in K$

How exactly the mentioned theorems are applied?

For the relevants theorems:

[image]

And

[image]

Comment: The $E_L$ are compact and the collection of all such satisfies the finite intersection property (if no $E_L$ is empty). For the other question, note that every linear functional on $\mathbb R^n$ has the form $\Lambda x=\sum \alpha(x)a_i$ where $x=(a_i)_i.$ The inequality arises from an application of the separation theorems (consequences of Hahn-Banach)

Comment: You seem to have two separate questions here. It is best to post two separate questions. Furthermore most people aren't going to have your version of the book to hand, so you should provide the relevant theorems

Comment: @Matematleta how is theorem 3.20 used? I assume to construct or prove the conditions of the theorem 3.4 are met.

Comment: Also if $E_L$ is compact for every choice of $E_L$ how does the FIP follows? I'm not sure I follow, I know that any compact space has such property, but here the property is for the intersections of $E_L$. I might miss something here.

Comment: Thm $3.20 d$ shows that the separation thm $3.4$ applies. $\{E_L\}_{L\in I}$ is a collection of compact sets that have FIP,  by the very definition of $E_L$. which implies that $\bigcap_{L\in I} E_L\neq \emptyset.$

Comment: @Matematleta I am reading the very same theorem and I have the same doubt. Why does the family $\{E_L\}_{L \in I}$ have the FIP?

Comment: @Bremen000 If $L$ and $L'$ are given then consider $L\cup L'.$

Comment: @Matematleta Thank you very much: I was confused with intersection of point and of $L$ and $L'$, it was simple!

Comment: I also needed that last comment by @Matematleta. +1